# Implicit call stack in the exception type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to store call stacks in the exception types. I can add `HasCallStack` constraint to the exception type like that:

```
data AException = HasCallStack => AException !String !Int
  deriving (Typeable, Exception)
deriving instance Show AException
```

Is it possible to extract the call stack from such type, without profiling enabled?

As a workaround I could put `CallStack` field explicitly into exception type and fill it every time manually, but I'm wondering if this can be done automatically?

Comment: From what I recall, constrained datatypes are unintuitive and nearly useless, and GADTs work better in almost all cases. Perhaps: `data AException where AException :: HasCallstack => !String -> !Int -> AException`.

Comment: Also, `!String` isn’t what it looks like; it only forces the string to WHNF, which means either nil or the first cons. Consider something like `Text` if you need a strict `String`; the same applies for `Vector`s and lists.

Comment: @jlwoodwa: You’re referring to `DataTypeContexts` (1. `data HasCallStack => AE = AE !String !Int`) but this is either `ExistentialQuantification` (2. `data AE = HasCallStack => AE !String !Int`) or `GADTs` (3. `data AE where { AE :: HasCallStack => !String -> !Int -> AE }`). It just looks curious because there’s only a context, no actual quantification or specialisation. Incidentally, #3 also works with `ExistentialQuantification` and `GADTSyntax` together instead of `GADTs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use `callStack`.

```
getCS :: AException -> CallStack
getCS (AException _ _) = callStack
```

It is important that you pattern match; this brings the `HasCallStack` constraint witness into scope.